# How to find corresponding revision of an exported folder with Git

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

How can I find the corresponding revision of an exported source folder with Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `git-bisect` and a custom script that diffs your export and the checkout as a *callback*.

Comment: To my understanding bisect won't work because it needs a bug that enters history and stays (ALL new revisions) , while the exported source corresponds to only ONE revision?